# Remove default value from Ant Design Select dropdown

Tags: typescript, antd, categories

I am using Ant Design <Form.Item> to display a list of categories. Is there a way to remove by default selected value.

```
          <Form.Item
                  label='Description'
                  name='description'
                  // rules={[{ required: true, message: 'This field is mandatory' }]}
                >
                  <Form.Item name='description'>
                    <Typography.Text type='secondary'>
                      Let your attendees know what to expect, including the agenda, what they need to bring, and how to
                      find the group.
                    </Typography.Text>
                    <ReactQuill theme='snow' value={description} onChange={setDescription} />
                  </Form.Item>
                </Form.Item>

                <Form.Item label='Category' name='category'>
                  <Select
                    mode='multiple'
                    bordered={false}
                    placeholder='Select category'
                    onChange={(value) => setSelectedCategories(value)}
                    style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', padding: '5px', border: '1px solid #999db6' }}
                    
                  >
                    {categories?.map((categories, indexValue) => (
                      <Select.Option
                        key={indexValue}
                        value={categories.key}
                        
                        disabled={
                          selectedCategories?.length === 5 && !selectedCategories?.includes(categories.key) && true
                        }
                      >
                        {categories.value}
                      </Select.Option>
                    ))}
                  </Select>
                </Form.Item>
```

I get one default value I cannot remove (see image), I tried using defaultValue={disable} on  but to no avail. What am I missing? [image]

Answer (score 0):

`Form.Item` offers a property `initialValue`. However if you don't set it it should be undefined by default, maybe you can provide a minimal working codesandbox I can take a look.

```
<Form.Item 
  label='Category' 
  name='category'
  initialValue={undefined} //should be undefined by default
>
...
</Form.Item>
```